# How to explicitly write a Selenium WebDriver screenshot to a directory in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am working on Win7 with PyCharm3. I have a functional test 'y1.py' which I have exported from the selenium IDE. It contains:

```
class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_y1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Weather").click()
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file('foo.png')    

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the script from the pycharm manage.py tool I realized that the screenshots are being saved to

```
PyCharm 3.0.1\jre\jre\bin"
```

Also, for some reason specifying the path explicitly does not work :

```
(driver.get_screenshot_as_file('c/foo1.png') ).
```

I've tried variations of this based on [Webdriver Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot), but can't get it to work. How could I use python to directly save the screenshot to a directory "screenshots" under my project root?

Edit:

I realized that there is a difference b/w the command line's manage.py and pycharm's tools->manage.py ( which is what I've been using ). When you run it from the command line the tests run much faster and the screenshot saves in the project's root directory ( which is what I wanted ). Hope this helps someone. - Bill

Comment: did you really try `c/foo1.png`?  this is not a valid path.. how about `C:\\foo1.png`

Comment: I did try this and others in the post above. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have success with `get_screenshot_as_file()` but I offer an alternative using `get_screenshot_as_base64()`.  Define this function in another module:

```
def save_screenshot(self, driver, file_name_prefix):
    img_str64 = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    f = open("screenshots/%s.png" % file_name_prefix, "wb")
    f.write(img_str64.decode("base64"))
    f.close()
```

Then, in the test replace

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('foo.png')
```

```
module_containing_this_function.save_screenshot("foo")
```