# Click a checkbox with selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tumblr, webautomation

I'm testing my app with tumblr and I have to log in and out as I go through procedures. While doing so, I'm having trouble clicking a checkbox that keeps popping up. How can I use selenium-webriver in python to click it?

I've tried selecting xpaths, ...by_ids, and by_classes, they won't work, so now I'm trying to use the mouse's coordinates to physically click the item. (This is on the tumblr login page, fyi)

[image]

Above is the html of the item I'm trying to select.

(EDIT:)
I've the following selectors:

```
#checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor")
#checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("g-recaptcha") 
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-token']")
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#recaptcha-anchor")
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
#driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-token").click()
#driver.find_element_by_class_name('rc-anchor-center-container')
#checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor")
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact url? I cannot see the checkox on log in page? Plus, provide the exact css/xpath you tried to see if there is any bug in them

Comment: https://www.tumblr.com/login is the exact url, they checkbox will appear when when you have logged in and out a couple times via tumblr. @Saifur

Comment: Cannot reproduce. tried at least 5 times

Comment: The attributes mention recaptcha... is this some bot prevention dialog?

Comment: Its the captcha checkbox thingy, I'm trying to click it @JeffC

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is a simple example that works for me in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("checkbox_id")).click();
```

In Python, it seems to be:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_id").click()
```

Answer (score 7):

I realise this is an old thread, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.  In the end I figured it out as follows.

Note 1: this will tick the recaptcha box, but it won't solve it, you'll still need to do that manually.

Note 2: this is on macOS, so you might need a different format for chrome_path on Windows

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#modify line below to location of your chromedriver executable
chrome_path = r"/Users/Username/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.btcmarkets.net/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_id("userIdText")
username.send_keys("Us3rn4me")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("userPasswordText")
password.send_keys("Pa55w0rD")

#the line below tabs to the recaptcha tickbox and ticks it with the space bar
password.send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not an input tag. So, probably manipulating the `aria-checked` attribute and set it to `true` would do it. The only way to change attribute value is JavaScriptExecutor. Try the following:

```
driver.execute_script("$('#recaptcha-anchor').setAttribute('aria-checked','true');")
```

Comment: when I use this code, it'll just click it or something?

Comment: It should check the checkbox. And, I assumed it would work without knowing the dom structure

Comment: i tried a wait 10 seconds and then your code, but still got an error

Comment: I really need to see what's happening on the page. It's hard to pinpoint the issue without knowing the actual cause

Comment: can we go into a chat?

Comment: Not directly from here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89022/discussion-between-marriedjane875-and-saifur).

Answer (score 0):

Use code below can find the checkbox with id "recaptcha-anchor" and click it, but unable to bypass it. The following pictures will pop up.

```
List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    String winHanaleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.id("recaptcha-anchor")).click();
driver.switchTo().window(winHanaleBefore);
```