# Selenium not working on server as it works on local machine

Tags: python, selenium, centos, pyvirtualdisplay

I have recently completed my Selenium Python scraper. It works totally fine when I run it on my personal machine but the results are not same when I run it on the server. On the server I am running headless using `pyvirtualdisplay`

```
browser.get('https://example.com')  
html = browser.page_source
```

And this is my code for pyvirtualdisplay.

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

While running on local machine, it totally grabs the HTML which is generated by JavaScript but when I run it on my server it doesn't grabs the HTML content generated by JavaScript, so I end up with only a partial page with none of the JS generated content.

**Update:**
I have also took screenshots as per suggestions using Selenium. Screenshot shows that the page is partially loaded and the content by JS isn't loaded onto the screen.

Comment: How is `browser` defined? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe `browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: On the server, is it running on an actual GUI or in a frame buffer (headless)?

Comment: I've run into issues like this before, it can be a number of things. What are you using for your frame buffer? Can you also include the command you are using to run your tests on the server?

Comment: Also can you include an example of what you expect to get vs what you actually get?

Comment: I use `python script.py`. The same I use on my local machine. I've implemented the scraper in Flask framework. And I am using pyvirtualdisplay for my frame buffer.

Comment: I expect to get a fully loaded page. Some of the site HTML is generated using JavaScript which I need to get using `browser.page_source`.

Comment: I understand that, but can you give us an example of what you expect and what you get? Are you getting a partial page or no page at all? and for pythonvirtualdisplay what is the framebuffer?

Comment: I am getting a partial page. The content which is loaded by the JavaScript is not present in the HTML I get through `browser.page_source`. On the other hand, when I am running the script in local machine, I am getting a full page.

Comment: Can you show us your code for pythonvirtualdisplay as well?

Comment: Added in the post.

Comment: Ok last question (I hope). What browser are you using, are they same version on both machines?

Comment: I am using Firefox. And yes, they are the same versions. Firefox 44.0.2 to be precise.

Comment: And same type of OS? Try taking a screenshot and seeing if the page even renders right

Comment: My local machine has Ubuntu 14.04 and the server has CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with your OS or Browser configuration. The first thing you should do is screenshot the results in your framebuffer and make sure that firefox is loading JS content properly. If it is not then you may need to check your browser/OS configurations.

pyvirtualdisplay has a way of screenshot that you can look at [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay)

specflow can also screenshot, instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot)

If it is a FireFox/Browser issue, be sure that you have installed all the proper plugins and Java needed to run javascript on your server. Make sure that javascript is enabled for that browser.

Comment: I have a Ubuntu server too. For the first time I tested the script on that server, it worked flawlessly. But when I ran the script again it didn't work with the same problem like on CentOS server. And on CentOS server, it didn't work even once. 

Thanks for recommending the screenshots. I am looking into them and will notify you.

Comment: So as you suggested, I have also took screenshots. Screenshots show that the page is partially loaded and the content by JS isn't loaded.

Comment: @abhanan93 So the issue isn't selenium then. Its your OS, your framebuffer, or your browser

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect suggestions