# How to take screenshot in selenium webdriver in Chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I am learning selenium Webdriver. I was trying to take screenshot on chrome browser but I got exception for below code (Note: Same piece of code works on firefox). Kindly help me out to take a screenshot on Chrome and please somebody explain me why below code is not working on Chrome.

```
public class ScreenShot 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String key  = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
        String value = "./driver/chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty(key, value);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File srcFile = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File destFile = new File("d:/google.png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Print your stack trace and make sure yoiur chromedriver is present at the location.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public static String captureScreenshot (WebDriver driver, String screenshotName){

    try {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String dest = "/Users/CD6255ABQA/Desktop/Debug Images/" + screenshotName + ".png";
        File destination = new File(dest);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        return dest;
        } 

    catch (IOException e) {return e.getMessage();}
    }
```

Call it using

```
String screenpath = captureScreenshot(driver, "ScreenshotName")
```

Remember to change the file destination in the method.

Answer (score 0):

In Django(Python), you can take the screenshots of Django Admin on headless Google Chrome as shown below. *I use [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot-in-python/77106289#77106289) explains it more:

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

def take_screenshot(driver, name):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join("screenshot", os.path.dirname(name)), exist_ok=True)
    driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join("screenshot", name))

def test_1(live_server):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
    take_screenshot(driver, "admin/chrome.png")
    assert "Log in | Django site admin" in driver.title
```