# How to take a screenshot in firefox headless (selenium in java)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I have been able to run a selenium test case with headless Firefox, However when taking a screenshot, the screenshot is not that of the web-page(web-page tested in the testcase) rather, the screenshot is taken of the background (as in. the current window shown (e.g. eclipse IDE running the testcase))

Screenshot function

```
File screenShotFolder = new File("Screenshots");
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        try {
            if (!screenShotFolder.exists() && !screenShotFolder.mkdir()) {
                getLog().error(
                        "Cannot create a new file in the intended location. "
                                + "" + screenShotFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            File scrFile =
                    ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String filePath =
                    screenShotFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                            + imageName + ".png";
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(filePath));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

is there any other "options" or "arguments" that need to be set?

Comment: The function I posted was working correctly, the issue was another function was taking the background screenshot and adding it to the final report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a screenshot with headless Firefox should work like for usual driver.

In the past I used the following approach:

```
public static String makeScreenshot() {
    String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "Test";
    File screenshot = Driver.driver.get().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File outputFile = new File("LoggerScreenshots/" + fileName + ".png");
    System.out.println(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, outputFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputFile.getName();
}
```

And called it when test execution fails:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can still use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument( "--headless" )
# options.add_argument( "--screenshot test.jpg http://google.com/" )
driver = webdriver.Firefox( firefox_options=options )
driver.get('http://google.com/')
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
print driver.title
print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django(Python), you can take the screenshots of Django Admin on headless Firefox as shown below. *I use [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot-in-python/77106289#77106289) explains it more:

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

def take_screenshot(driver, name):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join("screenshot", os.path.dirname(name)), exist_ok=True)
    driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join("screenshot", name))

def test_1(live_server):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
    take_screenshot(driver, "admin/firefox.png")
    assert "Log in | Django site admin" in driver.title
```