# How to save screen shot in some particular directory or folder in Python selenium testing

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

How do I save a screen shot in a particular directory or folder in Python selenium testing

```
try:
    assert driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Please enter unique details']")
    except AssertionError:
        print "We found some issuse -- Provide some unique details"
        log_test_case("Link Generate Failed", "Fail")

    c_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Link_Generate_Failed-%s.png' % c_date)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used:

```
    from pathlib import Path

    data_folder = Path('C:/<path to folder>')
    file_to_save = data_folder / ('post' + str(counter) + '.png')
    screenshot.save(file_to_save)
```