# Selenium how to save screenshot to specific directory in Python

Tags: python, selenium, path, screenshot

I would like to take a screenshot for my selenium driver and save it to a specific directory. Right now, I can run:

```
driver.save_screenshot('1.png')
```

and it saves the screenshot within the same directory as my python script. However, I would like to save it within a subdirectory of my script.
I tried the following for each attempt, I have no idea where the screenshot was saved on my machine:

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Screenshots', '1.png')
driver.save_screenshot(path)
```

```
driver.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/1.png')
```

```
driver.save_screenshot('Screenshots/1.png')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webdriver Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900073/webdriver-screenshot)

Comment: No, none of those solutions are working for me.

Comment: I've tried get_screenshot_as_file() and didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a kinda hacky way, but it ought to work for your end result...

```
driver.save_screenshot('1.png')

os.system("mv 1.png /directory/you/want/")
```

You might need to use the absolute path for your file and/or directory in the command above, not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file path you want to the `save_screenshot` function.

As your doing this already a good thing to check is that `os.getcwd` is the same as the location of the script (may be different if your calling it from somewhere else) and that the directory exists, this can be created via `os.makedirs`.

```py
import os
from os import path

file_dir = path.join(os.getcwd(), "screenshots")
os.makedirs(file_dir, exist_ok=True)

file_path = path.join(file_dir, "screenshot_one.png")
driver.save_screenshot(file_path)
```

If `os.getcwd` is not the right location, the following will get the directory of the current script..

```py
from os import path

file_dir = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
```